# Программа "Unity Editor" не работает

Tags: c#, unity3d

[**Копия на Unity Answers**](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1824504/unity-editor-does-not-work.html)

Во время выполнения кода:

```
void OnCollisionEnter()
    {
        Sphere.SetActive(false);
        Renderer REND = GetComponent<Renderer>();

        if (REND.material.color == new Color(1, 0, 0))
        {
            SphereCounter.Performed[SphereCounter.MissionProgress] = RGB.Red;
            SphereCounter.MissionProgress++;
        }
        else if (REND.material.color == new Color(0, 1, 0))
        {
            SphereCounter.Performed[SphereCounter.MissionProgress] = RGB.Green;
            SphereCounter.MissionProgress++;
        }
        else if (REND.material.color == new Color(0, 0, 1))
        {
            SphereCounter.Performed[SphereCounter.MissionProgress] = RGB.Blue;
            SphereCounter.MissionProgress++;
        }
    }
```

Unity перестает отвечать и пишет:

[image]

Если отладить, будет:

[image]

Затем откроется VS и напишет:

[image]

[image]

Если нажать "Продолжить", будет:

[image]

В чем здесь проблема и как ее исправить?

*P.S. Переустановлю Unity*

*P.P.S. Не помогло*

*P.P.P.S Переустановлю Windows*

*P.P.P.P.S Помогло, но теперь [VS не ставится](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1264712/visual-studio-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F)*

Comment: А если отлажить код - на какой именно строке вылетает Юнити?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1260003/4 - про ntdll.dll

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, на строке `SphereCounter.Performed[SphereCounter.MissionProgress]...`