# Visual Studio не запускается

Tags: visual-studio

Microsoft Visual Studio Community не работает сразу после установки. Пробовал переустановить, использовал devenv.exe. Не помогло. Как это исправить?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: В последнем окне есть разумный совет: "Откройте Visual Studio Command Line  с правами администратора, введите команду devenv.exe /resetsettings". Обязательно проверьте, чтьо команда выполнилась (что не написал какую нибудь ошибку). Можно и по другому: откройте обыкновенное cmd-окно с правами администратора, зайдите в нём в папку с devenv.exe, и выполните эту самую команду сброса настроек. Напишите, что получится. Хотя, судя по кол-ву ошибок, это может быть какой то "нехороший, испорченный дистрибутив"

Comment: @S.H. Запустил от имени админа. Студию открыл, но окно с редактором. Если запустить VS как обычно - те же ошибки

Comment: Тогда рекомендую такую штуку: 1) деинсталлировать 2) удалить всякие ошмётки, такие, как c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft\, %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio и т.п. - лучше просто поиска по диску. Также, почистить реестр. 3) перезагрузиться 4) заново скачать дистрибутив 5) установить от имени администратора, предварительно отключив антивирус (некотрые из них много о себе думают). Надеюсь, поможет!

Comment: @S.H. не помогло